# Is it possible to use MultipleColumn in VB ListBox

Tags: vb.net

Im not able to use MultipleColumns in ListBox.  I've  set ListBox1.MultiColumn attribute to true. ListBox1.ColumnCount says ColumnCount is not a member of ListBox

Comment: Indeed, there is no property named ColumnCount in a WinForm ListBox. Can you explain exactly what are trying to do? Probably MultiColumn is not what you are looking for.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please elaborate your questions and ask specific questions only.

Comment: Use a DataGridView

Comment: As suggested, if you want to display tabular data then use a `DataGridView`. You can use a `ListView` with the `View` set to `Details` but you generally shouldn't. The `ListView` is not a grid control. If you're not using the grouping functionality or multiple views then you should not be using a `ListView`.

Answer (score 2):

Please notice that a Multi-Column ListBox does NOT mean that you can add several columns (such as a datagridview). When you set `ListBox1.MultiColumn = True` it only means that ListBox1 places items into as many columns as are needed to make vertical scrolling unnecessary. You can test it by decreasing the height of ListBox1 and then adding many items. You will see something like this:
[Multi-Column ListBox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlMGo.png)

As you can see, ListBox1 automatically puts items in multi columns and there is no Vertical scrollbar.
For more information, you can see [ListBox.MultiColumn Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.multicolumn?view=netcore-3.1#System_Windows_Forms_ListBox_MultiColumn) from Microsoft documents.